# Missing manifest Resource exception while accessing es-mx resource file in class library project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am getting following error while accessing key in spanish resource file.

> {"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure \"TokenService.Resource.Resourcess.resources\" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly \"TokenService.Resource\" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."}

I have a separate class library project for resource files which contains culture specific resource files.

> Project name of class library project :TokenService.Resource

I have added reference of this class library project to my website project (asp.net website project).
I am setting the culture:

```
 CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(Request.UserLanguages[0]);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
 lnkForgotPwd.Text = TokenService.Resource.Resources.ForgotPwd;
```

i am getting error at last line in above code.
I have set the culture to `es-MX`

What additional settings or code i have to do ???

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the Access Modifier of the Resource to Public:

[image]